# xsane detects scanner but freezes when scanning

Tags: hardware, canon, pixma, xsane

I am running xsane 0.998 on ubuntu 14.04. When I start xsane, it correctly identifies my USB scanner as a Canon Pixma MP540 - but when I click the scan button - xsane freezes.

However scanimage >image.pnm and Simple Scan both work fine

```
$ scanimage -L 
    device `pixma:04A91730_114002' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MP540 multi-function peripheral

$ lsusb
    ...
    Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04a9:1730 Canon, Inc.
    ...

$ sudo sane-find-scanner
    ...
    # No USB scanners found.
    ...
```

any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by getting rid of the user xsane directory, like so:

```
mv $HOME/.sane/xsane $HOME/.sane/xsane.bak
```